# Cordova 3.0 - Open link in external browser in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

How do you open links in the devices native browser when using Cordova 3.0 on iOS?

People have suggested using `window.open( url, "_system" )` but this does not work in Cordova 3.0.

**My Attempt**

```
if( navigator.app ) // Android
    navigator.app.loadUrl( url, {openExternal:true} )
else // iOS and others
    window.open( url, "_system" ) // opens in the app, not in safari
```

Does anyone know of a solution that works with Cordova 3.0?
Thanks

Comment: Check my 2015 answer here to open `_self` in WebView, and `_blank` in external browser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208609/cordova-why-would-inappbrowser-plugin-be-required-to-open-links-in-system-brows/32227524

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**NOTE**: to make `window.open('somelink', '_system')` to work you now need a device-level plugin, the inAppBrowser. Here are the installing instructions as of Cordova 3.0

From the Docs for 3.0:

As of version 3.0, Cordova implements device-level APIs as plugins. Use the CLI's plugin command, described in The Command-line Interface, to add or remove this feature for a project:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
$ cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.core.inappbrowser
```

These commands apply to all targeted platforms, but modify the platform-specific configuration settings described below:

iOS (in config.xml)

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>
```

I just tested this and it works.

Comment: Worth noting that it appears the InAppBrowser plugin enables handling of `_system` links as well ([http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#window.open](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#window.open))

Comment: @dannytenaglias go ahead and put that in your answer. Something like: NOTE: to make `window.open('somelink', '_system')` to work you now need a device-level plugin, the inAppBrowser. Here are the installing instructions as of Cordova 3.0:

Answer (score 4):

install InAppBrowser plugin:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
$ cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.core.inappbrowser
```

and execute the plugin in your .js file:

```
//exec(successCallback, errorCallback, pluginName, pluginMethod, params)
cordova.exec(null, null, "InAppBrowser", "open", [url, "_system"]);
```